# Rotating, scaling Cocos2d inherited layer with 2 sprites as children

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c++

Straight to the point, I have a class which is basically inherited from CCLayer and has 2 sprites as children.

some_layer.h

```
@interface some_layer : CCLayer {
    CCSprite *back;
    CCSprite *front;
}
```

some_layer.mm

```
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        back = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"back.png"];
        front = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"front.png"];
        [front setOpacity:0];
        [self addChild:back];
        [self addChild:front];
        //this is after modification
        back.positionInPixels = CGPointMake(winSizeInPixels.width/2,winSizeInPixels.height/2);
        front.positionInPixels = CGPointMake(winSizeInPixels.width/2,winSizeInPixels.height/2);

    }
    return self;

}
//after the edit
    -(void) setPositionInPixels:(CGPoint)positionInPixels {
        [super setPositionInPixels:CGPointMake(positionInPixels.x -(winSizeInPixels.width/2), positionInPixels.y -(winSizeInPixels.height/2))];
    }

    -(void) setPosition:(CGPoint)position {
        [super setPosition:CGPointMake(position.x -(winSize.width/2), position.y -(winSize.height/2))];
    }
```

Of course that is not all the implementation of the layer, but that code is the only one related to the problem, let me know if you think you need more.

Now in some part of the parent layer am trying to do this

```
    float x = winSizeInPixels.width/2;
    float y = winSizeInPixels.height/2;
    [self setPositionInPixels:CGPointMake(x, y)];
    mylayer = [[some_layer alloc] init];
    [mylayer setPositionInPixels:CGPointMake(-offset, -offset)];
    [self addChild:mylayer];
    [mylayer runAction:[CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:speed*20 angle:angle] rate:4]];
```

The output of this code, is that I can see the sprites rotating, but not around the center of some_layer, I want them to rotate and stay in their place (rotate around themselves), what am trying to do is rotate, scale them at the same time while keeping their positions the same on screen,

The sprites are keeping in rotating around some random point ( Maybe around parent of their parent which is self in the last code )

BTW, I'm not touching the sprites back and front positions, I only deal with that "some_layer", I tried setting their positions to (0,0)

The only time the position of "some_layer" is correct is when it's rotation angle is 0, and it's scale is 1.0, if there's something unclear please let me know, thanks a lot, I can provide some screen shots

Edit : I modified the code above, it works properly as a workaround, but I think this is not the right way of doing it!!! Please check the comments, I don't know what's strange happening!!

Thank you!

Edit 2: Answer found

Answer to my self

Add this to the init method of some_layer.mm

```
[self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
```

Thanks for everyone who tried to help me :)

Analysing the code is the best solution!

BTW I deleted the overridden methodes for both setPos and deleted the code that changes the Sprites positions, it's like this now

```
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        back = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"back.png"];
        front = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"front.png"];
        [front setOpacity:0];
        [self addChild:back];
        [self addChild:front];
        [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
    }
    return self;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting some anchorPoint for the Layer or Sprite which you are using. if yes then please check that the anchor point should be set at center :

someSprite.anchorPoint=ccp(0.5,0.5);

For more details : http://www.qcmat.com/understanding-anchorpoint-in-cocos2d/

Comment: can you please explain what this method [self setPositionInPixels:CGPointMake(x, y)]; do here..

Comment: It's setting the position of the layer to the offset which is basically 150

Comment: The elements rotate about themselfs after adding this to the init methode

Comment: There is huge difference between setPosition and setPositionInPixel please don't override it, use setPosition and .position only, because setPositionInPixel and .positionInPixel will show you different results with different resolutions screen.

Comment: I understand the difference exactly, I use set positions in pixels because I have all the positions in pixels, I'm porting a game that have all positions in pixels, everything works as expected, I'm only worrying about the sprites not rotating around themselves

Comment: Also I don't want to override them, it's just the reason for testing, I want to fix it and then delete the overriding code

Comment: I will mark this as correct because you talked about anchor points, pixels and that helped me a lot in testing out the code and knowing the answer, anchorpointinpixel was totally wrong, it wasn't zero!!